# How to make an "image only" floating action button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image as below.

[image]

When I use it to make a floating action button, the button looks like this.

[image]

I don't want the pink margin. I only want my image to be shown. What should I do?

I also want the size of my image to be the outer circle not the inner one.

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh" />
```

Comment: changing the src attribute will only set the icon drawable which have fixed size.
You shouldn't change background attribute either.
Why not changing the background tint to green and setting the icon with only the arrow ? 
Otherwise I think you should use a custom imagebutton instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered to use only an `ImageView` ?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh" />
```

Than in your `ActivityMain.java`

```
ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fab);
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // Your code here
  }
});
```

Or more specifically an `ImageButton` ?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh" />
```

Than:

```
ImageButton v = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // Your code here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Android Studio gave me the floating action button when I create a new tabbed activity. I thought using FAB is necessary for tabbed activity to show a floating button. But now I am sure it's not.

Answer (score 8):

Im not sure that this solution as acceptable, but it works;

You can override image size dimension for nested image in FAB.
Just add to your dimens file:

`<dimen tools:override="true" name="design_fab_image_size">56dp</dimen>` (I used 56dp cause fab size in guidelines is 56dp)

tools:override="true" - this is the thing why I suppose that this solution is not good, cause "design_fab_image_size" - is final, and you should insist on overriding :)

Comment: this worked for me. Just in case someone wonder where to add this, its in your values->dimens.xml. Don't forget to add `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in your `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own class extends FloatingActionButton and add this lines in the constructor

```
super(context, attrs);
Method method = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getSizeDimension");
method.setAccessible(true);
Object r = method.invoke(this);
Field f = super.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mMaxImageSize");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(this, r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the dimension of the icon to 56px in Illustrator/Photoshop. Then make sure you add `android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"` this to make the fab color transparent.